# Kivy - Get value from Toggle Buttons Group

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm starting with Kivy. I want to make a toogle button group and get a value depending which button is pressed.

My code is working, but I wonder if there is another way to do this.

Here is my code:

**The "building.kv" file:**

```
#:kivy 1.10

<CategoryButton@ToggleButton>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 48,48
    markup: True
    group: 'category'


<Category@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    current_value: 1
    CategoryButton:
        text: '[b]I[/b]'
        on_press: root.current_value = 1
    CategoryButton:
        text: '[b]II[/b]'
        on_press: root.current_value = 2
    CategoryButton:
        text: '[b]III[/b]'
        on_press: root.current_value = 3
    CategoryButton:
        text: '[b]IV[/b]'
        on_press: root.current_value = 4

    Label:
        text: str(root.current_value)
```

**The "buildingmodule.kv" file:**

```
#:kivy 1.10

<BuildingWind>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Category:
```

**The python file**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class BuildingWind(BoxLayout):
    pass

def build(self):
    return BuildingWind()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    aplication = BuildingModuleApp()
    aplication.run()
```